# How to get current currency code of current location in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, .net, geolocation, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

I locate the current location - Country and Country Code, but how to get the currency code of this location in Windows Phone 8.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either make a network call to a web service to map country code to currency code or embed a list of country code to currency code mappings in your app.

Here's an example of a web service providing the mapping.

http://country.io/currency.json

```
...
"US": "USD",
"UY": "UYU",
"UZ": "UZS",
"VA": "EUR",
"VC": "XCD",
...
```

Comment: http://www.nationsonline.org/oneworld/country_code_list.htm I found this cool list of CountryCodes, but cannot find nowhere their respective CurrencyCodes to do a mapping in my app..

Comment: Go to the link I posted and copy and paste the text into a file in your app.  Now you have country code to currency code mapping.